# Why do some Jelastic providers block Export Environment option

Tags: jelastic

According to Jelastic documentation it is possible to export the Environment configuration and download it so it can be restored in another provider

However I have tried with 2 Jelastic providers and they both have disabled the option for exporting private data.

So exporting/download/upload/import of environment is not possible.
i.e. I was expecting to have a process similar to CPanel backup/restore tool

Answer (score 0):

In fact, another view for the deployment process gives a possibility to get rid of the model of handling the data or configuration on the platform. Try to think a bit differently and using CI/CD approach. The Jelastic provides a platform where something you created, locate on somewhere you're elaborating(VCS or GIT as an example) and based on or depends on the specific stack, already pre-configured like a layer and can be installed(copied) over Jelastic. Don't need to handle the data somewhere in the cloud because you have it locally(means within any VCS) and doing the changes there. Then just do a 'pull' procedure(*manually or automatically*) on that deployment(*test, production, staging*) environment you're expecting. 
Moreover, you can expect any environments type like a code and perform it creating before deploying the data.

Please, find the articles being described each case:

- [Deployment Guide](https://docs.jelastic.com/deployment-guide)
- [Jelastic Packaging Standard for CI/CD Automation](https://docs.jelastic.com/jps)

In case you would like to handle the databases' backups, check this article:

- [Scheduling Database Backups](https://docs.jelastic.com/scheduling-backups)

Additional FTP add-on can make the copies more easily for each instance:

- [FTP/FTPS Support in Jelastic](https://docs.jelastic.com/ftp-ftps-support)